# Connecting to MS SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to connect to a MS SQL Server to access the database. The client has given me an IP address, Username and Password.

When using these credentials, I am able to login on (on my Mac) using the Microsoft Remote Desktop app from the app store.

But when I attempt to connect using a SQL Server client, SQLPro for SQL Server and/or HeidiSQL on PC (VirtualBox), I am prompted with:

> Login failed for user '{USERNAME}'. Adaptive Server connection failed

Does anyone have tips on why this is happening and how I can connect to the database?

Comment: Try connecting to <IP>:<PORT> if the default port is not changed, it is 1433. if it still doesn't work, then SQL is not configured for Remote Connection

Comment: SQL Server may not be configured to allow remote connections.

Comment: Are you using the same credentials for MSSQL as you are for RDP? The user principals are not necessarily shared.

Comment: I assume (you don't say) that you are connecting with the SQL Server client using a SQL Login. This is completely different to a windows login (which is what you log into RDP with). I've never seen 'Adaptive Server connection failed' for SQL Server - are you sure it's Microsoft SQL server?, not Sybase?

Comment: I am now connected. Sure enough, I needed to add a user to the database and set the correct permissions. I am now connected and pulling in data into the Laravel app. Thanks all.